# How can I make Perl's a2p support gawk?

Tags: perl, awk

I have some awk scripts that use gawk from cygwin. Now I need to pass these scripts to colleagues that don't have cygwin installed, but do have Perl. I was hoping I can just use a2p that is included in cygwin, but it fails with errors like the following:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::gensub called at ./t.pl line 18, <> line 1.
```

I am hoping there are existing Perl libraries/modules that implement these methods. Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `gensub()` function isn't supported by `a2p`. If you modify your code to use `gsub()` instead then it should compile.

Alternatively, you could add a `gensub()` subroutine to the end of the translated Perl program to simulate the `gensub()` functionality.

However, the Perl code produced by `a2p` isn't very maintainable so I'd only use it as a last resort.

If your gawk program doesn't make calls to other cygwin/unix utilities then it would probably be better to just distribute a Windows gawk executable to your colleagues along with the program.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was also trying to learn a bit of perl using a2p. Your response helps.